# Count and Substring the number

Tags: mysql, sql

Based on the format given e.g. `PPYYNNNN` and `Word = EXO`, 
I need to get count of "P" in the format.
Based on the number of "P" I need to get the word.

e.g. number of "P" = 2, and word = EX

If count of "P" equals to 2 then it gets 2 first letters from the word 
and if count of "P" equals to 1 then it gets first letter from the word

Tried using `substring` but could not work

Any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select left('EXO', length('PPYYNNNN') - length(replace('PPYYNNNN', 'P', '')))
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70660)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
select left(str2, String.LastIndexOf('P', str) - string.indexOf('P', str))
in your example str='PPYYNNNN' and str2='EXO'.